# How can I send emails to a phone number?

Tags: email, send, verify

As a freelance developer I work for clients from whom I've created signup/sign in forms to acquire users using their mobile/phone numbers. I.e. users enter their phone number and OTP to verify their phone numbers.

Is is possible to send emails to phone numbers once users have registered on my web/app products ?

Comment: This is not possible. Email and phone are separate systems.